# UUID is same from different strings

Tags: java, uuid

I have two different strings, but after parsing to UUID it's seem to be same

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UUID t1 = UUID.fromString("38e1036d-7527-42a3-98ca-f2f19d3155db");
        UUID t2 = UUID.fromString("123438e1036d-7527-42a3-98ca-f2f19d3155db");
        System.out.println(t1.toString().equals(t2.toString()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any idea why it is?

Comment: What output do you get? What output do you expect? What happens if you print the two results rather than comparing them?

Comment: Maybe because the UUID's are exactually the same except for the `1234` at the begining? What if you alter the rest of the UUID instead of adding 4 digits at the beginning?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. It should throw some kind of exception telling you it's not a valid UUID.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> "123438e1036d-7527-42a3-98ca-f2f19d3155db"

This is not a UUID. It's a concatenated string of "1234" and a UUID. The problem here is that the parser should have told you this by throwing an exception. Instead it tries its best to actually find the UUID buried somewhere in there.

Once you extract the UUID from your concatenated string, it's identical to the first UUID which is the correct result you're observing.

We can analyze the parser (thanks to @tim-biegeleisen for providing the link):

```
public static UUID fromString(String name) {
    String[] components = name.split("-");
    if (components.length != 5)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid UUID string: "+name);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        components[i] = "0x"+components[i];

    long mostSigBits = Long.decode(components[0]).longValue();
    mostSigBits <<= 16;
    mostSigBits |= Long.decode(components[1]).longValue();
    mostSigBits <<= 16;
    mostSigBits |= Long.decode(components[2]).longValue();

    long leastSigBits = Long.decode(components[3]).longValue();
    leastSigBits <<= 48;
    leastSigBits |= Long.decode(components[4]).longValue();

    return new UUID(mostSigBits, leastSigBits);
}
```

As we can see, there is no validation except for counting the number of groups limited by hyphens. It just takes those groups and then shifts them into positions. You've added extra characters in front of the first group, which is the most significant part. It's parsed and stored first, and then it gets shifted up and again up until it occupies the most significant part. Now, all bits that were farther left than assumed get pushed out of the `long` limit, hence they're completely ignored.

Comment: @Raedwald Well, validation being present by default is more a matter of convention. I don't know Java well enough to say what the convention is.

Answer (score 53):

A [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) stores [128 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit) of data. If you give it more it can't store them. I am surprised it doesn't give you an error, but not surprised it truncates the higher bits otherwise.

```
int i = 0x38e1036d;
int j = (int) 0x123438e1036dL;
i == j;
```

Comment: For anyone who wants to see what the source code is actually doing: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/UUID.java#UUID.fromString%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: it truncated but seeming when `mostSigBits` or 'leastSigBits' is more than 64bits

Comment: I'd file a bug for this. My best guess for why they did this would be that maybe they intended to allow each section of the UUID to be *shorter* so that leading zeros aren't required? I dunno.

Answer (score 9):

The bit shifting of the second component '7527' removes the effect of the modification you made to the first component '123438e1036d' which results in the same UUID being generated.

The processing of the first component by itself is different but this effect is lost when the second component of the uuid is shifted.

Answer (score 4):

That is because it checks from right to left, and takes only 32 characters as UUID, and removes others. once 32 character in order is taken, it doesnt care about others, as it implements Serializable interface.

```
public final class UUID
  extends Object
  implements Serializable, Comparable<UUID>
```

1234 is trimmed from you 2nd UUID.

Here is its code, it helps much better

```
 public static UUID More ...fromString(String name) {
    String[] components = name.split("-");
    if (components.length != 5)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid UUID string: "+name);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        components[i] = "0x"+components[i];

    long mostSigBits = Long.decode(components[0]).longValue();
    mostSigBits <<= 16;
    mostSigBits |= Long.decode(components[1]).longValue();
    mostSigBits <<= 16;
    mostSigBits |= Long.decode(components[2]).longValue();

    long leastSigBits = Long.decode(components[3]).longValue();
    leastSigBits <<= 48;
    leastSigBits |= Long.decode(components[4]).longValue();

    return new UUID(mostSigBits, leastSigBits);
    }
```

Comment: If it goes "left to right" and "takes only 32 characters" then `55db` would be the portion ignored.  But it isn't....

Answer (score 4):

This is known bug in Java 8, reported in June 2016:
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8159339

See also http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8165199 (reported in August 2016):

> 4d4d8f3b-3b81-44f3-968d-d1c1a48b4ac8 is a valid UUID.
>
> 4d4d8f-3b3b81-44f3-968d-d1c1a48b4ac8 is not (moved the first dashes two characters to the left)
>
> Calling UUID::fromString() with the invalid one results in an UUID representing 004d4dbf-3b81-44f3-968d-d1c1a48b4ac8.